# Button click from partial view redirects to Parent action method

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a View 'Parent' in my application , I am using @Html.BeginForm & a submit button to save data of Parent view . I also have one partial view inside Parent view , I am trying to call ajax method(using jQuery) from partial view but each time it redirects me to action method of parent form.

```
Parent View
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test1", "Home", new { id = 1 }, FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.Partial("TestPartial", Model)
    <div>
        <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="Parent" />
    </div>
}

Partial View
<script>
function onClientClick() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Test2",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ ID: 1 }),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function (err, result) {
            alert("Error" + err.responseText);
        }
    });
}
</script>
<div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="onClientClick()" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Each time i am trying to call /Home/Test2 from Partial view it redirects me to /Home/Test1(Action of parent form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="onClientClick()" value="Submit" />
```

The type is `submit` therefore it is submitting the form and redirecting you to the Action in the parent.

In your partial view have a regular `button` not a `submit button` to request the `AJAX` content:

```
<input type="button" onclick="onClientClick()" value="Ajax Call" />
```

You could also `return false` however I believe using the standard `button` rather than `submit` is more suited in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Return `false` after calling the ajax... at the end of `onClientClick` function

**OR** Re-Write your submit as

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

and then in jquery bnd the click event as

```
$("submit").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault()
$.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Test2",
        type: "GET",
.
.
. 

});
```

**OR** Change the `input` type from `submit` to `button`